# highchart csv export custom filename and value

Tags: javascript, csv, highcharts

```
  Please refer below JS fiddle link.
  https://jsfiddle.net/2pd1natw/1/

// this is my JS for reference
  $(function () {
    var k = 0;
    $('#container').highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            zoomType: 'xy',
            events: {
                drilldown: function (e){
                    if (!e.seriesOptions) {
                        var chart = this,
                        drilldowns = {
                            '2015':{
                                name: '2015',
                                data: [
                                    ['Q4-2015',89]
                                ]
                            },
                            '2016':{
                                name: '2016',
                                data: [
                                    ['Q2-2016',95],
                                    ['Q3-2016',99]
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        drilldownsLines = {
                            '2015':{
                                type: 'spline',
                                name: '2015',
                                data: [
                                    ['Q4-2015',11.45]
                                ],
                                yAxis: 1
                            },
                                '2016':{
                                type: 'spline',
                                name: '2016',
                                yAxis: 1,
                                data: [
                                    ['Q2-2016',11.2],
                                    ['Q3-2016',11.5]
                                ]
                            }
                        },
                        series = drilldowns[e.point.name],
                        seriesLine = drilldownsLines[e.point.name];
                        chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, series);
                        chart.addSingleSeriesAsDrilldown(e.point, seriesLine);
                        chart.applyDrilldown();
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Rental & Capital Value Trend'
        },
        exporting: {
                enabled: true,
            csv:{
                columnHeaderFormatter:function(item, key, series){
                    if(key === '' || key === undefined){
                        return 'Period';
                    }else if(key === 'y' && k == 0){
                        k = k + 1;
                        return 'Rental Value (INR/SF/Month)';
                    }else if(key === 'y' && k == 1){
                        k = 0;
                        return 'Capital Value (INR/SF)';
                    }
                }
            },
            buttons:{
                contextButton:{
                    menuItems: [{
                        textKey: 'downloadCSV',
                        onclick: function (){
                            this.downloadCSV();
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        },
        xAxis: {
            type: 'category',
        },
        yAxis: [{
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: 'Rental Value (INR/SF/Month)'
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value}'
            }
        }, {
            min:0,
            tickInterval:5,
            title: {
                text: 'Capital Value (INR/SF)'
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} K'
            },
            opposite:true
        }],
        tooltip:{
            formatter:function(){
                var s='';
                $.each(this.points, function () {
                    if(this.series.type == 'spline'){
                        s += '<br/>Capital Value : ' + this.y+ 'K';
                    }else{
                        s += '<br/> Rental Value : ' + this.y;
                    }
                });
                return s;
            },
            shared:true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'horizontal',
            align: 'left',
            size: '12px',
            x: 50,
            verticalAlign: 'bottom',
            y: 20,
            floating: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                borderWidth: 0,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                }
            }
        },
        series: [{
                name: 'Renatl Value (INR/SFT/Month)',
                color: '#EE8908',
                data: [
                    {
                        name: '2015',
                        y: 89,
                        drilldown: true
                    }, {
                        name: '2016',
                        y: 90,
                        drilldown: true
                    }
                ]
            },{
                name:'Capital Value (INR/SF)',
                color:'#F8BB6C',
                type:'spline',
                yAxis:1,
                data:[
                    {
                        name:'2015',
                        y:11.45
                    },{
                        name:'2016',
                        y:15.22
                        }
                ],
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: 'K'
                }
            }
        ],
        drilldown: {
            /*activeAxisLabelStyle: {
                textDecoration: 'none'
            },*/
            series: []
        }
    });
});
```

There are two scenarios where I got stuck.

1. when I try to export chart as csv after drill down downloaded file name should be "Quarterly rental-capital trend" and before drill down "Yearly rental-capital trend".
           e.g. before drill down file name should be like "Yearly rental-capital trend.csv"
               after drill down file name should be like "Quarterly rental-capital trend.csv"
2. after exporting to csv the capital value should be append with "K".
   e.g. period | rental value | capital value
        2015 | 90 | 11.15 K

   Any help will be appreciated and thanks and advance.

Comment: 1. There is exporting.options called filename which can be set to define a filename for an exported file. You can change it on drilldown and drillup.
2. To modify the output of the csv, you need to wrap the methods for generating data and csv string. Example [here](https://jsfiddle.net/vcd9qac5/) - you should also set some kind of flag to preserve the default behaviour if you wrap export-csv module many times

Comment: thanks @morganfree